# I'm having a trouble creating this new activity - Udacity Project Sunshine Lesson 3

Tags: java, android, xml

Because the class is somewhat old, and the IDE changed so much, i'm struggling a bit trying to do the same steps of the class.
I have created my Intent and i can send it by clicking on the ListView Item. Then it switches activities from the MainActivity to the DetailActivity. Yet when the DetailActivity is displayed (using DetailActivityFragment) the toolbar disappears. I compared XML's and made some improvements but now the toolbar isn't populated like the previous toolbar. The activity also "fills" the notification bar (the bar that extends to the drawer).
Question is, what am I doing wrong and what can i do to replicate the MainActivity toolbar to the new DetailActivity?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.diomonogatarilaptop.sunshine;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Something", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            MainActivityFragment.FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new MainActivityFragment.FetchWeatherTask();
            weatherTask.execute("Buraca");
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

DetailActivity.java:

```
package com.example.diomonogatarilaptop.sunshine;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container_detail, new DetailActivityFragment())
                        .commit();
            }
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_detail);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    public static class DetailActivityFragment extends Fragment {

        TextView textView;
        public DetailActivityFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Intent intent =getActivity().getIntent();
            View rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

            if(intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
                String forecastStr = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                textView= (TextView) rootView.findViewById((R.id.detail_text));
                textView.setText(forecastStr);
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }




}
```

Activity_detail.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_detail" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content_detail.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.diomonogatarilaptop.sunshine.DetailActivity$DetailActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail"
    />
```

Fragment_detail.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.diomonogatarilaptop.sunshine.DetailActivity$DetailActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_detail">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/detail_text"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Some ScreenCaptures from debugging on my mobile:

[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maAzT.png)

[DetailActivity Where the bug happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLAnL.png)